# Making Porcelain Tile Smoother

Tags: tile

My wife and I are redoing our bathroom. We got a sample piece of grey glazed porcelain tile and really like the look of it, but after having the piece on the floor in the bathroom for barely a couple weeks, we realized that it grabs hair, fuzz, and dust, and it's hard to clean. It has to be scrubbed by hand to get it clean. Would using some kind of tile sealer on it after installation create a smoother surface that would be more easily vacuumed and mopped with something like a wetjet? I'm new to tile, but in my mind, the sealer would act like polyurethane for wood, which with the right prep and application, makes wood smoother to the touch. Am I completely wrong? Would we be better off looking for different tile? If the sealant idea is worth a shot, what sealant would you recommend?  (copied from my post on Reddit r/homeimprovement)

[The tile in question](https://www.lowes.com/pd/GBI-Tile-Stone-Inc-Dove-Grey-Gray-Glazed-12-in-x-24-in-Glazed-Porcelain-Floor-and-Wall-Tile/1002627268)

Comment: There are various commercial porcelain tile sealants. *Caveat!* Be sure that it does not make a bathroom floor dangerously slippery. Perhaps a floor scrubbing robot might help cleaning?

Comment: Question is do you really want a smooth floor with soap and water around.  A bit of texture on the floor sounds better than a head split open.

Comment: I would think that a tile sealer would be designed to seep into the porous surface of a non-glazed tile. A porcelain tile has a (microscopically) smooth, sealed surface and the sealer won't seep in. I think you're looking for it to puddle and fill the macroscopic irregularities, but I don't think it'll do that...